# How do the anti-D antibodies help prevent Hemolytic Disease of the Newborn? And why do they not act like the maternal antibodies?

Tags: immunology, hematology, antibody

I understand that this question has been asked a few times in the past, but the answers there didn't really explain to me why the Anti-D antibodies we introduce are able to prevent the hemolysis of foetal RBCs, and why they aren't identical to maternal antibodies.

As I understand it, HDN is caused when, after the first pregnancy, the mother's body makes antibodies to the D antigen of an Rh+ve foetus, and in subsequent pregnancies, these antibodies cross the placenta and destroy the foetal RBCs.

How do the exogenous anti-D antibodies help prevent this?

Regarding what I didn't understand:
[Why is the administration of exogenous Anti-D not harmful to the foetus?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35531/why-is-the-administration-of-exogenous-anti-d-not-harmful-to-the-foetus)

> This is exactly what the makers of RhoGAM suggest, saying that the amount of antibody administered at 28 weeks into the pregnancy is sufficient to block any Rh antigen on Red Blood Cells that escape into the mother's blood, but insufficient to cross the placenta and be a problem. At this time the child will be large enough that any RhoGAM that does cross the placenta will not kill enough Red Blood Cells to harm the child.

I thought that the problem was the maternal antibodies crossing the placenta, how does blocking antigens of foetal RBCS leaking into maternal blood help? Isn't it the leaking of maternal blood into the foetus which lets the Anti-D antibodies attack the D-antigen and cause erythroblastosis?

And either way, don't the maternal antibodies do the same thing as RhoGAM, i.e. attaching to the D antigens?

Comment: If other questions relate to yours, or other references you've read elsewhere on the internet, it's helpful if you cite and link to these answers and explain what they've said and where you are stuck exactly.

Comment: Thanks, edited.